# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restplus'

Tags: flask-restplus

I am trying to install flask_restplus on a virtual conda environment.
I am sure that I am in my env but when I use pip install it seems to install the flask_restplus in a different environment (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (which is not my virtual env directory). i tried to use conda install flask_restplus and I get this error:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- flask_restplus

I tried to copy the site packages from the other env to this conda env and that didn't work
I tried to create a new conda env and re-intsall and that didn't work
I tried to use the /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base as a base for my conda env and that didn't work
i tried to use conda install -c conda-forge flask-restplus and that didn't work

Comment: According to the docs, `flask_restplus` is best installed using `pip`. Make sure that `pip` is also installed *inside* your conda environment and you use exactly that version, such that `pip` will recognize this and install it's packages also inside that env.

Comment: Hi philipphutterer
I have pip installed in my env and i used pip install but when i do that pop seems to place it in a different env

Comment: Maybe try installing pip with the create env command? There might be some error like described [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429). In general, can you reproduce this with another new conda env?